# How to find Duplicates in table with more than one column ID , COL1 , COL2 and COL3

Tags: sql, duplicates

How we can find duplicate rows in table with more than one column e.g
table is 
[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5pRl.jpg)

```
EMPID   FNAME   LNAME
 1      VIKAS   AHLAWAT
 1      VIKAS   AHLAWAT
 2      NIKITA  JAIN
 3      ASHISH  KUMAR
 4      NIKHIL  SHARMA
 5      ANISH   KADIAN
 6      ANISH   KADIAN
```

and expected result should be as below

```
EMPID   FNAME   LNAME
1       VIKAS   AHLAWAT
1       VIKAS   AHLAWAT
5       ANISH   KADIAN
6       ANISH   KADIAN
```

[image: Table 2]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate based solution will work in all the databases:

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join (
    select fname, lname
    from your_table
    group by fname, lname
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t2 on t1.lname = t2.lname
    and t1.fname = t2.fname
```

If you are using a database which supports window functions, you can use:

```
select empid, fname, lname
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over (partition by fname, lname) cnt
    from your_table t
    ) t
where cnt > 1
```

If you want just the name who are present multiple times (and not their empids):

```
select fname, lname
from your_table
group by fname, lname
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks but first qurey result is 
ID     FNAME    LNAME
1 VIKAS AHLAWAT
1 VIKAS AHLAWAT

Comment: @user2528069 - No. It produces the exact same result are you expect. See this demo - http://rextester.com/MYC52928

Answer (score 0):

This query will show you the required results.

```
select count(empid) cnt, 
        empid,
        fname, 
        lname
  from table_1
 group by fname, lanem
 having count(empid) > 1
order by 1 desc
```